# How to link against Vulkan with MinGW and QMake?

Tags: c++, qt, mingw, qmake, vulkan

I tried to link against Vulkan with:

```
LIBS += -L$$(VK_SDK_PATH)/Bin -lvulkan-1 # Doesn't work at all
LIBS += -L$$(VK_SDK_PATH)/Lib -lvulkan-1 # Works with MSVC
```

But I couldn't get it linking with MinGW.

#### INSTALLED:

- VulkanSDK (1.2.148.1)
- Qt (5.15.0; MSYS2)
- MinGW (10.2.0; MSYS2)

Comment: It may be useful to show us the actual error output you're getting.

Comment: This is the error output
`[...]/x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lvulkan-1`
`collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I installed the Vulkan Runtime and retried

```
LIBS += -L$$(VK_SDK_PATH)/Lib -lvulkan-1
```

with MinGW again and it works. Nevertheless, thank you for helping me out.